# Reading in CSV while ordering/dropping variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read in a df with the goal to have it match a certain format/order.

So I want the df to be exactly in the same variable order and any missing variables remain empty.

`var_list = ['Gender','Age','Region','Income','Education']`

Actual list is 300+ variables

so final df headers should be in same order as var_list, but if the variable doesn't exist in file being read it should create it and leave it empty.

I'm sure I could just create an empty data frame and join on that, but trying to make it part of the read_csv function and have played around with usecols, but handling the missing variables is causing me some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to make basic "if check" if colunms are not listed.
Example,

```
def get_data(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    if 'x_colunm' not in list(df.columns):
        print("x_colunm are not listed")
    else:
        print("Access Data")
        print(df.shape)
    return df
```